# Number of paths in high-girth graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In a graph $G$ with girth $g$, say $g = \Omega(\log n)$, can we deduce an upper bound on the number of paths between two nodes $u$ and $v$?

Comment: This is a great question. If you don't care about regularity, take any bounded-degree graph with lots of paths between two vertices and replace each edge with a path of $\log n$ vertices, then the girth will be large. This isn't very interesting, but I do suspect that the girth bound may not limit the number of paths

Comment: My suspect is that if the max-degree is $\Delta$, then the number of paths is bounded by $\Delta^{O(n/g)}$.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Let us consider the set of *all* paths of $G$ nevermind the ending points (as there are only $n^2$ such choices for the starting and ending points this is OK). Let us call a walk *legal* from a starting vertex $u_0$ if it is a path. I would imagine that for "many" legal walks $W$ of length $\ell < \epsilon n$ in $G$, there are at least (say) $\frac{k}{3}$ ways to extend $W$ to a legal walk of length $\ell+1$. This should imply $\exp(\Omega(n))$ total paths which would imply a $u-v$ pair such that there are $\exp(\Omega(n))$ paths between $u$ and $v$

Comment: We could also assume that $G$ is an expander of course as there are high-girth expanders, and there are even explicit constructions of such graphs